# Firebase Swift 3.0 Syntax Update?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I have had an Firebase-backed iOS app that has been working well until I upgraded Xcode to Xcode 8. Now errors show up in lines such as:

`let state = child.value!["STATE"] as! String // Was correct in Swift 2.3`

Error in Swift 3.0: `Value of type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no member 'value'`

After Converting my code to Swift 3.0, the change made the syntax into this:

`let name = (child as AnyObject).value!["NAME"] as! String`

But that returns this error:

`Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'`

Additionally, I am getting this error: `The Type 'Any' has no subscript members` when I try to access a snapshot value.

Firebase docs have not changed for Swift 3.0, so what is the issue here?

Full Code Block:

```
 self.firebase.child(“INFO”).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in

            for child in snap.children{

                if child.hasChild("NAME") && child.hasChild("ZIP-CODE") && child.hasChild("STATE"){

                        let name = child.value!["NAME"] as! String
                          let zip = child.value!["ZIP-CODE"] as! String
                          let state = child.value!["STATE"] as! String

                }
            }

        })
```

Thanks for all help, it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are not casting your retrieved **Snapshot** from an event to any type, Which might lead the Xcode confused as to what type does this **Snapshot** even belong to?

```
   FIRDatabase.database().reference().observeSingleEvent(of : .value, with : {(Snapshot) in

        if let snapDict = Snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
            for child in snapDict{

                if let name = child.value["NAME"] as? String{

                    print(name)
                }
                if let zip = child.value["ZIP-CODE"] as? String{

                    print(zip)
                }
                if let state = child.value["STATE"] as? String{

                    print(state)
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not solve my issue. I just updated the full code there for you

Comment: Whenever directly calling .value on a FIRDataSnapshot, the error reads: `Type 'Any' has no subscript members`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting child.value as an NSDictionary? I've had success casting my firebase snapshots and accessing their values the following way (adapted to your situation).

```
self.firebase.child(“INFO”).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        for child in snap.children{
            let childValue = child.value as? NSDictionary

            if child.hasChild("NAME") && child.hasChild("ZIP-CODE") && child.hasChild("STATE"){

                    let name = childValue!["NAME"] as! String
                      let zip = childValue!["ZIP-CODE"] as! String
                      let state = childValue!["STATE"] as! String

            }
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar issue, had to recast the children as a `DataSnapshot` (renamed from `FIRDataSnapshot`) for some reason.

So something like this:

```
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
            if let childSnapshot = childSnapshot as? DataSnapshot,
                let data = childSnapshot.value
                // Do stuff with data
            }
        }
    })
```